# show one div but hide all other divs is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one jQuery code which show/hide the extra info on click. But I have a requirement, so that when one info is opened, the other info should be hidden. i.e when a particular link is clicked, that info should be opened and other info should be hidden. How to do that?

**CSS**

```
.linkinfo {  display: none; }  
.nn { margin: 5px 0 5px 0; font-weight: bold;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.link').on('click', function () {
        $(this).text(function (i, txt) {
            return txt.indexOf('MORE') != -1 ? 'HIDE' : 'MORE';
        }).closest('.nn').next('.linkinfo').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
Red blood cells (RBCs) principal means of delivering oxygen to the body tissues.
<a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a><div class="linkinfo">
Also called erythrocytes. 
</div><br>

White blood cells (WBCs) are the cells of the immune system against infectious disease. 
<a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a><div class="linkinfo">
Also called leukocytes.
</div><br>

Platelets are blood cells whose function  is to stop bleeding.
<a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a><div class="linkinfo">
Also called thrombocytes.
</div><br>
```

Comment: where is the element with the class `.nn` ?

Comment: change `.closest('.linkinfo').slideToggle();` and try

Comment: .nn class is for the hyperlink; and it is stylish pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this solution is helpful

I have added `notselected` class by default to all the `a` tags

html

```
  Red blood cells (RBCs) principal means of delivering oxygen to the body tissues.
<a class="link notselected" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a>

<div class="linkinfo">Also called erythrocytes.</div>
<br>White blood cells (WBCs) are the cells of the immune system against infectious disease.
<a class="link notselected" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a>

<div class="linkinfo">Also called leukocytes.</div>
<br>Platelets are blood cells whose function is to stop bleeding.
<a class="link notselected" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a>

<div class="linkinfo">Also called thrombocytes.</div>
<br>
```

jquery

```
$('.link').on('click', function () {
$('.link').not(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('notselected');
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

    $(this).addClass("notselected").removeClass('selected');
} else $(this).removeClass('notselected').addClass("selected");

toggleLabel();
});

function toggleLabel() {
    $('.selected').text("HIDE");
    $(".notselected").text('MORE');
    $('.selected').next('.linkinfo').slideToggle();
    $(".notselected").next('.linkinfo').hide();

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/5U3Xc/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3dE9V/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.link').on('click', function () {
        var $link = $(this).text(function (i, txt) {
            return txt.indexOf('MORE') != -1 ? 'HIDE' : 'MORE';
        }).next('.linkinfo').slideToggle();
        $('.linkinfo').not($link).slideUp();
    });
});
```

*Note: Your example data has no `.nn` class applied to the elements, but you do not actually need it.*

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to solve your problem but i could not change the title

Please try this

```
Red blood cells (RBCs) principal means of delivering oxygen to the body tissues.
<a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a>
<div class="linkinfo">
Also called erythrocytes. 
</div><br>

White blood cells (WBCs) are the cells of the immune system against infectious disease. 
<a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a><div class="linkinfo">
Also called leukocytes.
</div><br>

Platelets are blood cells whose function  is to stop bleeding.
<a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a><div class="linkinfo">
Also called thrombocytes.
</div><br>
<style>
.linkinfo{
display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.link').on('click', function () {
        $(this).text(function (i, txt) {
            return txt.indexOf('MORE') != -1 ? 'HIDE' : 'MORE';
        }).next('.linkinfo').show().siblings('.linkinfo').css( "display", "none");

    });
});
</script>
```

Hide show is working fine but more and hide is not working in this query